# The server is not running

Tags: express

The server is not running with the code below:

```js
import express from 'express';
import mongodb from 'mongodb';

const app = express();
const dburl = 'mogodb://localhost/crudwithredux';

mongodb.MongoClient.connect(dburl, {useNewUrlParser: true}, function (err, db) {
    app.get('/api/games', (req, res) => {
        db.collection('games').find({}).toArray((err, games) => {
            res.json({games});
        });
    });

    app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Server is running on localhost:8080'));
});
```

---

```
`{
  "name": "crud",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mogodb": "^3.1.9",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-router": "^4.4.0-beta.8",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000"
}
`
```

Comment: Please update your post with what the actual issue is, and what you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified a port for the mongodb server.Specify the port in the connection url.Console log the err, to check if there is some issue in the mongo connection because without a successful mongodb connection your express server won't start.

Secondly, you should not write an api endpoint inside the mongo connect function instead you should grab a database object and reuse it everywhere.

Following is the proper way of doing things:

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const app = express();
const dburl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/crudwithredux';
var db;

mongodb.MongoClient.connect(dburl, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err,database) {
   if(err){
   console.log('An error has occurred', err);
   } else {
   db = database;
   app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Server is running on localhost:8080'));
}
});

app.get('/api/games', (req, res) => {
        db.collection('games').find({}).toArray((err, games) => {
            res.json({ games });
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks for help! now if i run: node server.js then i have this error: {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
and in console i have this: GET http://localhost:3000/api/games 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)

Comment: can you post your package.json file here?

Comment: i could not add json file here?! over characters!

Comment: `{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node -- ./server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.3.0-beta2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  }
}
`

Comment: this is the backend json file

Comment: you should not an answer for this, edit your question and add package.json there

Comment: I have updated the code and corrected few typos, kindly run the above and let me know if the problem persists

Comment: were you able to fix?